First item in UITabBarController's 'More' tab not showing up properly when using storyboard and run on device with ios 18.0
Problem with "More" Tab in UITabBarController on iOS 18
I'm working on an iOS application using Objective-C and UITabBarController. I have more than five tabs, so the additional ones are placed under the "More" tab. However, when I click on the "More" tab in iOS 18.0, the first item does not show up properly. This issue does not occur in iOS 17 or earlier versions.


Development Environment

Xcode Version: 15

Deployment Target: iOS 17


Steps to Reproduce

Create a new iOS project in Xcode and set the deployment target to iOS 17.

Delete the default main storyboard and add a new UITabBarController as the initial view controller.

Populate the UITabBarController with more than five tabs so that the additional ones appear under the "More" menu.

Run the app on an iOS 18.0 simulator or device.

Navigate to the "More" menu in the tab bar.


Expected Behavior
All items in the "More" menu should appear as expected.
Actual Behavior
The first item in the "More" menu does not appear initially but is visible when editing the menu.
What I've Tried

Verified that each view controller is correctly initialized and has a title and image.

Logged the contents of the moreNavigationController to confirm that it contains the correct view controllers.

Tested by reducing the number of view controllers to fewer than five, which resolves the issue but is not a viable solution for the app.

Ensured all navigation controllers are configured consistently (e.g., translucency, bar style).


Additional Notes

The issue only occurs when the UITabBarController is set up using the storyboard. When initialized and configured programmatically, the problem does not occur.

The behavior is specific to iOS 18.0; everything works as expected in iOS 17.


Workaround

To temporarily avoid this issue, initialize and set up the UITabBarController programmatically instead of using the storyboard.

What could be causing the first item under the "More" tab to not show up correctly on iOS 18 when using a storyboard configuration? Any insights or suggestions for debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated!
You can find a minimal code example that reproduces this issue on my GitHub: iOS 18 UITabBarController Bug Repository.

Nice demo; actually you only need six vc's (on a small simulator) to see the problem. Four items appear in the tab bar, one item appears in the More list; one item is missing. You could do quite a bit to simplify and clean up the example before sending it to Apple.

Personally I wouldn't waste time waiting for an "answer" on Stack Overflow; you won't get one. It's clearly a bug, you've proved it, you've got an easy workaround, report it to Apple and move on. Thanks again for documenting this so clearly.

Please I would request anyone seeing this to report also, as the apps using this code are in production and clients  are reporting that  menu is not there
